# In latex how to escape "{" in \verb in tabularx environmnet?

Tags: latex

I tried `\verb|\{|`, and it will print `\{`. If using `\verb|{|` without the backslash, an error would occur that says `! File ended while scanning \TX@get@body`

Use the following to replicate this error on Overleaf or WinEdt:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ll}
    \hline
    \verb|{| & Error. \\ % The use of \verb|{| here generates the error!
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I the above code, "\verb|{|" will generate the error.

With the kind help from samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, I understand now that "{" can be displayed in tabularx using \listinline{{}. But this gives a plain-text style "{". Is there a way to make the "{" more code style? See the below picture for comparison.[image: what I am looking for]

Comment: `\verb|{|` without the backslash? Do you mean that it throws an error when you use `verb|{|`?

Comment: yes, exactly, when you are using it in tabularx.

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for future questions. Is is quite confusing if the parts of the code, you are asking about, aren't visible in your questions.

Comment: the "\verb|{|" will generate the error, right near the "Error" part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `listings` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX}
    \hline
    \lstinline{\}} & Error. \\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It works and now I can print "}" in a tabularx environment in text style. Is there a way to make it \verb|| style?

Comment: You can change the font with `\lstset{basicstyle={\ttfamily}}`

Comment: Thanks. Works fine for me now. I just noticed that this is the second time you helped me out.